# Metric under which $C([0,\infty );\mathbb{R})$ is a Polish space.

Tags: metric-spaces

Does there exist a metric such that $C([0,\infty ); \mathbb{R})$ is a separable complete metric space? The usual supremum norm isn't even a metric on this space and I've tried several variants e.g. 
$$d(f,g) = \sup_{K cpct} \frac{d_K(f,g)}{1+d_K(f,g)}$$

where $d_K$ denotes the supremum norm over the compact set $K$. But, the space is not separable under this metric and several of its variants.

To see this suppose that ${f_n}$ a countable dense subset (wlog indexed by $\mathbb{N}$) then define $f(x) = f_n(x) + 1$ if $x=n$ and linearly interpolate otherwise. This $f$ will be at least a fixed distance from all the $f_n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about giving less weight to points far from the origin? You could try $$d(f,g) = 
\sum_{k=1}^\infty 2^{-k} \frac{d_{[0,k]}(f,g)}{1 + d_{[0,k]}(f,g)}.$$

For each $k$ let $\{f_{k,n}\}$ be a sequence in $C([0,\infty))$ that is dense in $C([0,k])$ in the supremum norm.

If $f \in C([0,\infty))$ and $\epsilon > 0$ you can select $N$ so that $\displaystyle \sum_{k=N+1}^\infty 2^{-k} < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and choose $n$ so that $d_{[0,N]} (f,f_{N,n}) < \dfrac{\epsilon}{2}$.  Then $d(f,f_{N,n}) < \epsilon$.